# gradient over image using background-image is taller than the image it is above

Tags: css, gradient

with HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="bgimagegradient"></div>
  <img src="foo.jpg">
<div>

.backgroundimage {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px; 
    z-index: -100;
    height: 400px;

    .bgimagegradient {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 10%, rgba(0, 53, 107, .5));
    }
    > img {
        position: relative;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 0;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following behavior (gradient is too tall):

[image]

The error is at the bottom of the image, the gradient is about 4px taller than the image its over.

When the image, in a responsive context, is large enough to hit the container max width (outside of the HTML I've shown you) it works but scaled down to smaller responsive scenarios, I get this problem.

Comment: Create a pen so we can see better what is going on.Also, you forgot a closing } on .backgroundimage css

Comment: Have you tried tricks like `display: block;` or `vertical-align: bottom;` on your `img`? It looks like it could be caused by this common phenomenon.

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom;` did the trick!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few things incorrect:

- Your HTML uses class 'outer' and your CSS uses 'backgroundimage'.
- In the CSS for the gradient you refer to the width with 100%. However, the width is not defined for the parent.
- Use of z-index is not necessary.

Below I created what I believe you require. Hope this helps.

```css
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
.bgimagegradient  {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 10%, rgba(0, 53, 107, .5));
 }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400">
  <div class="bgimagegradient "></div>
<div>
```